# Change background color fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I know my question is ridiculous, but, I can't make this work.

I'm doing a web using jquery mobile where I want to change the background color of the body. I tried with my own css, but, jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css executes later than mine and it is not working. I tried changing it via javascript, but it is also not working. Some idea?

My CSS code:

```
html body {
    background-color: #c8065c;
}
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pageTitle").click(function() {
        $("body").css("background-color","rgb(200,6,92)");
    });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: It is still not working :(

Comment: you need a comma between HTM and body.. . html, body { ...

Comment: @gavgrif Since body is a child of html the comma is not necessary unless you want to target both elements separately.

Comment: I tested this and nothing

Comment: What is the exact style that is applied to the body by jquery mobile?

Comment: I would suggest not trying to alter the base CSS - but instead add or remove a class that has a color associated with it

Comment: @Turnip There are 129 matches of "body", but, it changes background color, color, border color...

Comment: @gavgrif I did it and not works

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331596/cant-change-jquery-mobile-background-color

Comment: @Turnip nothing...

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: two thoughts - do you have an element with an id of "pageTitle" to trigger the event adnsecondyly - try altering the CSS with a hex value not an RGB value - I can't see what that would change - but you never know

Comment: @Turnip You want the complete files?

Comment: No i don't want your files. I want you to create a simple example that shows the issue. Use jsfiddle.net or a StackSnippet here on SO.

Comment: @gavgrif I have "pageTitle" I tried with the background color of a div at same time, and div changes but body not. I was using now de RGB because HEX was not working and I wanted to try all before posting nothing here

Comment: @Turnip not sure if it was this, but here it is https://jsfiddle.net/3ksxbds1/

Comment: I’m going to delete my answer, since the wrong CSS comments apparently aren’t the issue; the JSFiddle doesn’t seem to have anything to do with [your actual page](http://basededatostoons.com/stack/index.html). In order to make this question suitable for Stack Overflow we’re going to need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question that directly demonstrates the issue. We’re going to need an example such that a solution for it will also work for your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You body is red, the problem is not it, the problem is that you have a white div overlaying the body:

[image: See this print]

Comment: You are a monster!! You found it. Thank you a lot, I have been looking for this f**ing background for hours.